# How would you build in criteria when using Random assign people to groups

Tags: python, random

I would like to assign people randomly to a group.  I have used the following code from an existing script but I would like to add a criteria where "Kimani" is always no. 2 in a group

```
'''
import random

participants= 
["Alex","Elsie","Elise","Kimani","Ryan","Chris","Paul","Chris1","Pau2l", 
"Chris3","Paul3"]
group=1
membersInGroup=5

for participant in participants[:]:               # only modification
if membersInGroup==5:
    print("Group {} consists of;".format(group))
    membersInGroup=0
    group+=1
person=random.choice(participants)
print(person)
membersInGroup+=1
participants.remove(str(person))
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
import math

Kimani_group = math.ceil(random.randint(1,len(participants)) / 5) # round up to the nearest random selection of a group 
participants.remove(str("Kimani")) # remove Kimani as their group has already been selected, just need to insert them


for count in range(len(participants) + 1): # add +1 to participants as Kimani was part of the count but removed; changed count to the index of the loop 
    if membersInGroup==5:
        print("Group {} consists of;".format(group))
        membersInGroup=0
        group+=1
    if count % 5 == 1 and math.ceil((count + 1) / 5) == Kimani_group: # check if the second position in the group and that the group is the preselected group
        print("Kimani")
        membersInGroup+=1
        continue # skip the rest of the code in this iteration and continue to the next iteration
    person=random.choice(participants)
    print(person)
    membersInGroup+=1
    participants.remove(str(person))
```

This makes Kimani number 2 in a group they join.

Comment: I just tried to copy in the code but get an error like: ValueError: empty rane for randrange()(1,1,0)?

Comment: `ValueError: empty rane for randrange()(1,1,0)` where is that in your code. its not part of what I provided.

Comment: Should I be able to run the code that you provided me without my own code. I thought your code was an add-on to my code.

Comment: you should be able to do either with the code provided. It seems that your randrange() has an extra set of paratheses before the values you would like to use though unsure as I can not see the rest of your code